# Changing an string to an integer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, integer

I am trying to create a 3 way combination table. My problem is that I am trying to create the table with ids that are strings. I am receiving through a rest api so when the api receives them, I would like rails to convert these strings to ids to use for the ids for the new combination table. How would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_i` to convert a string. For example:

```
x = "1"
x.to_i # 1
```

Comment: So my problem now is that the number getting sent to the rest api is a string and I need to convert that to an integer so it can be used a an id. I was trying to do this with `params.require(:classroom).permit(:period.to_i, :teacher.to_i, :subject.to_i)`, but that results in an error. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: might help to post more of your code and the api you are trying to use as well as the error messages....

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert params from string to integer.
You can convert them before you return

```
def classroom_params
    params[:classroom][:period] = params[:classroom][:period].to_i
    params[:classroom][:teacher] = params[:classroom][:teacher].to_i
    params[:classroom][:subject] = params[:classroom][:subject].to_i
    params.require(:classroom).permit(:period, :teacher, :subject)
end
```

I did not find and to_i in place method. Appreciated if any suggestion.